# Unwrapping NSMutableArray from NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults

I am trying to unwrap a NSMutableArray from user defaults, but keep getting the error `unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`. I tried to check for nil after getting the array, but it is happening on the line that is getting the array from the UserDefaults, so I don't know how to fix this error. Can anyone help?

```
var classURLs: NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray();
let defaults: NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults(suiteName: "group.myCompany.Array")!;
classURLs = NSMutableArray(object: defaults.objectForKey("Class URLs")!);
```

Comment: You may not have a key called "Class URLs".

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28919910/2303865

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSUserDefaults.objectForKey` returns an optional for a reason – if the key isn’t present, you get `nil` back.  You shouldn’t just force-unwrap it with `!`

The most common case is this is the first time you’ve tried reading it without having ever written it.

In which case you probably want a default value, perhaps an empty array:

```
let classURLs = defaults.stringArrayForKey("Class URLs") as? [String] ?? []
```

(`??` substitutes the value on the right if the value on the left is `nil`)

Note, it’s probably better if you’re writing Swift to go with a Swift array (e.g. `[String]`) rather than `NSMutableArray`, unless all you are going to do is pass it straight into a call to Objective-C.

You can also avoid the `!` you’re using with the `NSUserDefaults` init by using optional chaining:

```
let defaults = NSUserDefaults(suiteName: "group.myCompany.Array")
var classURLs = defaults?.stringArrayForKey("Class URLs") as? [String] ?? []
```

Answer (score 1):

If the key does not exist, the forced unwrap (`!`) of the `nil` object will result in a crash. You need to account for this case.

```
var classURLs = NSMutableArray(object:    
   NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("foo") ?? [])
```

*NB: transitioning from Objective-C? You don't need the semicolons! ;-)*